# Dapper shows "possible null reference return" error after updating

Tags: c#, .net, null, warnings, dapper

I have this code:

```cs
public async Task<T> QuerySingleOrDefault<T>(string sqlStatment, object parameters, CommandType commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure, int timeout = 90, EnumConnStrings ConnString )
{
    using SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_appSettings.DataSource.GetConnectionById(ConnString));
    return await connection.QuerySingleOrDefaultAsync<T>(sqlStatment, parameters, commandType: commandType, commandTimeout: timeout);

}
```

And now after updating Dapper it shows an error:

> possible null reference return

on the line with the `return` statement.

Has something changed in Dapper? What should I do to suppress or resolve this message?

Comment: You are probably looking for QuerySingleAsync? Single or default means that it will return default if a single is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As b166er's comment says, `QuerySingleOrDefaultAsync` will return a default value if it finds nothing. If you take a look at `QuerySingleOrDefaultAsync`, you can see it returns `Task<T?>` meaning that the default value will be null (because of `T?`).

You are returning the result of that call (which could be null) but your method returns `Task<T>`, that's why you get that warning.

To fix your warning, depending on your needs, you have to make sure you won't return null or change the return type of your method to `Task<T?>`